# What variables to use in jQuery easing animation

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using the grayscale bootstrap template for a wordpress theme. I have my scripts enqueued, but I'm not sure how to fix the syntax on the original javascript. The functionality works like this: click on a link and it slides you down to the id attribute. 
Here is the original code:

```
$(function() {
$('.page-scroll a').bind('click', function(event) {
    var $anchor = $(this);
    $('html, body').stop().animate({
        scrollTop: $($anchor.attr('href')).offset().top
    }, 1500, 'easeInOutExpo');
    event.preventDefault();
});
});
```

And I replace the $ with `jQuery` because of .NoConflict

```
jQuery(function() {
jQuery('.page-scroll a').bind('click', function(event) {
    var $anchor = jQuery(this);
    jQuery('html, body').stop().animate({
        scrollTop: jQuery($anchor.attr('href')).offset().top
    }, 1500, 'easeInOutExpo');
    event.preventDefault();
});
});
```

Then I get this error:

```
TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'x.easing[this.easing]        (e,this.options.duration*e,0,1,this.options.duration)')
```

The $anchor is local, so I'm sure it doesn't matter. Infact I've replced it also, but I get the same result. Any suggestions? Does the problem lie in this line `var anchor = jQuery(this);`?

Answer (score 1):

It turns out I was loading the wrong library. I needed to load the easing library instead of the jQuery UI library.